# swift - tableviewcell reload with animation with dispatch_async

Tags: swift, animation, uitableview

I an icon in my cells, when **fav** button is pressed I want to display it `without reloading the whole table`.

So I use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

This reloads the table instantly, I want a smooth animation. 
I found this, it seems that its working for objectiveC, How can I do this in **swift**?

```
/Put this code where you want to reload your table view
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView transitionWithView:<"TableName">
                          duration:0.1f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:^(void) {
                            [<"TableName"> reloadData];
                        } completion:NULL];       
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can use this method

```
class func transitionWithView(view: UIView, duration: NSTimeInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions, animations: () -> Void, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

It's equal to the code you used with OC.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to reload a table's section with animation is using something like this:

```
YOUR_TABLE.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) // You can try different UITableViewRowAnimations to see what you like
```

Edit: It should be noted, this will reload the first section of your table view with the specified animation. You can put this inside your async call as well.